# Docker Container Can't Find Package Even after install

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following repository structure (I know the names are stupid):

```
dummy/
  main/
    hello.py
    requirements.txt
  yips/ 
    yips/
      _init_.py
      lol.py
    setup.py
    
  Dockerfile
```

The idea is to run the program hello.py, which imports a method from lol.py in the Yips library. For testing purposes, I import sklearn in the lol.py despite not using it. My Dockerfile looks like the following:

```
FROM python:3.9-bullseye

WORKDIR /yips
COPY yips/ ./
RUN pip3 install .

WORKDIR /main
COPY ./main/ .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "hello.py"]
```

Requirements.txt has both sklearn and numpy, which is used in hello.py.

I have tried running the docker image and it complains that it cannot find sklearn and for what its worth, when I do not import it, everything works as fine (so there is not an issue with the numpy import in hello.py). I have also tried adding a direct call to pip install sklearn before installing my yips library. Does anyone have any insight on how to fix this?

Comment: Please show your `requirements.txt` contents and include the full error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might have put `scikit` in your `requirements.txt` when you should include `scikit-learn`.

[How to fix the error for the main use cases](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/)